# How to provide own follow redirect strategy?

Tags: reactor-netty

I'm interacting with a webservice which on POST request answers with 302 containing address to created resource in the location header. To access the created resource I've to make a GET request to the provided location.
I want `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient` to handle the redirect flow for me.
This is my configuration:

```java
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
...
...
var nettyHttpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .compress(true)
            .followRedirect(true);
```

With the above configuration, the client will use same HTTP method for the redirected request as it did for the first request.

Given my use-case, is there a way to provide my own redirect strategy to the client for 3xx responses?

Comment: do you use Netty `HttpClient` directly or as a part of the spring `WebClient`?

Comment: Reactor netty HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

You could handle raw response and handle http status `302` with custom logic

```
var response = nettyHttpClient.post()
    .uri("/test")
    .response()
    .flatMap(res -> {
       if (res.status().equals(HttpResponseStatus.FOUND)) {
         return nettyHttpClient.get()
             .uri(res.responseHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.LOCATION))
             .response();
       }

       return Mono.just(res);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm doing something similar now, however, I've to do it where evere there is a put/post in any of my applications, I am looking for globally configurable way to provide my own redirect strategy. I've done some digging in the code base of netty http and as it stands there is no way of doing it.